# Radio Group crashing application

Tags: java, android

Im having difficulty with the below. I believe the code to be correct, but when i go this activity it causes the application to crash?

Could anyone help me out and point out what I'm missing?

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;


public  class CanopySizer extends Activity implements RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener{

EditText CanopyLength, CanopyWidth;
TextView Volume;
RadioButton Light, Medium, Heavy;
RadioGroup Loadings;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.canopysizer);

    CanopyLength=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.CanopyL);
    CanopyWidth=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.CanopyW);
    Volume=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Volume);
    Light=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.Light);
    Medium=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.Medium);
    Heavy=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.Heavy);
    Loadings=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.Loading);
    Loadings.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

}


public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup Loadings, int aplication) {

    if (aplication==Light.getId()){
        double Canopylength = Double.parseDouble(CanopyLength.getText().toString());
        double Canopywidth = Double.parseDouble(CanopyWidth.getText().toString());
        double CanopyArea = Canopylength * Canopywidth;
        double ExtractionRate = CanopyArea * 0.25;
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
        Volume.setText(df.format(ExtractionRate));
    }
    if (aplication==Medium.getId()){
        double Canopylength = Double.parseDouble(CanopyLength.getText().toString());
        double Canopywidth = Double.parseDouble(CanopyWidth.getText().toString());
        double CanopyArea = Canopylength * Canopywidth;
        double ExtractionRate = CanopyArea * 0.35;
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
        Volume.setText(df.format(ExtractionRate));
            }       
    if (aplication==Heavy.getId()){
        double Canopylength = Double.parseDouble(CanopyLength.getText().toString());
        double Canopywidth = Double.parseDouble(CanopyWidth.getText().toString());
        double CanopyArea = Canopylength * Canopywidth;
        double ExtractionRate = CanopyArea * 0.50;
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
        Volume.setText(df.format(ExtractionRate));

    }
}

}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are not getting NumberFormatException?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well turns out just replacing the line `if (aplication==Light.getId()){`  with `if (aplication==R.id.Light){` has done the trick. The application is no longer crashing.

Cheers.